# Trunk 8 Text truncation

Tags: truncate

I'm working on text truncation with Trunk8. The plugin works fine but I want to fine tune the function to truncate text when screen size down to 480px. and un-truncated text when screen size is more than 640px?

here is the code, Thank you

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
if ($(window).width() <= 480) {

    // do something here
        $('#t8').trunk8({
        fill: '&hellip; <a id="read-more" href="#">>></a>'
    });

    $('#read-more').live('click', function (event) {
        $(this).parent().trunk8('revert').append(' <a id="read-less" href="#"><<</a>');
        return false;
    });

    $('#read-less').live('click', function (event) {
        $(this).parent().trunk8();
        return false;
    });

}

  });
```